# List all article pages facebook comments for moderation

Tags: facebook

Please help me regarding facebook comments moderation, for eg, 3 editors wrote 10 articles and they have to moderate the facebook comments via facebook dashboard and article wrote by another editor should not moderate the comments.

I am planning to do Page-based Moderation, so an editor can click the moderation tool link over top of the comments plugin and he can moderate it.

When none of the articles grows more, the editor is unable to open all the articles manually and do moderation by clicking on the moderation tool link.

Is there any way to list all the comments in a single Facebook dashboard in Page-based Moderation? respective editor?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to fetch a list of all your domain's URLs from Facebook, but because they're your URLs you should already have a list of them and can fetch the comments for each URL using the Facebook's API there's no API to let you make administrative changes to those comments; you'll need to use Facebook's tools for that purpose